# Shortest Path between two vertices with BFS

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search

Hi everyone I have some issues with BFS in particular with 2 vertices exercise.For example: I want to visit not all the vertices , but when I found my target I want to stop.  Is correct this pseudocode?(For the code I've been inspired by my Algorthm's book (Goodrich ,Tamassia )

```
BFS(Graph G,Vertex s,Vertex t)
{ Queue q;
  for( all v in G) mark_unvisited(v)
    mark_visited(s)
     q.enqueue(s)
   while(!Q.isEmpty())
    { u=q.front();
        if(u==target)     // is this correct ?
           { break}
         for(all w Adj[u])
           {     if(w==is unvisited)
                   { mark_visited(w)
                      q.enqueue(w)
                    }
            }
        q.dequeue()
   }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that's correct. As soon as you dequeue the node from the queue, you know that you've discovered the shortest path to it.

Hope this helps!